# How to add this list in React state

Tags: sql, reactjs

```
const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);
var Data=[]; 
useEffect(async() => {
    try{
        const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:7000/api/all');
        Data=res.data;
        console.log("data",Data);
        setRowData(Data);
        console.log("statedata",rowData);
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e.message)
    }
  },[])
```

Datalog
[image]

I want to put Data in rowData with setRowData.. I tried but...I can't solve it...
How to put Data in rowData?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be having any issues. Try using your state in view. it should work

Comment: I'm assuming your talking about that last console log? The state setter functions are asynchronous. In fact all it does is schedule a rerender sometime in the future, the component won't have the updated state until then. There's no problem with the code.

Comment: You was right I overlooked that're asynchronous.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this example

```js
const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);

const getData = async () => {
  try{
        const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:7000/api/all');
        setRowData(res.data);
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e.message)
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    getData()
},[])
```